# Python: why is in scrapy crawlspider not printing or doing anything?

Tags: python, scrapy, comments

I'm new to scrapy and cant get it to do anything. Eventually I want to scrape all the html comments from a website by following internal links.

For now I'm just trying to scrape the internal links and add them to a list.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

    class comment_spider(CrawlSpider):
        name = 'test'
        allowed_domains = ['https://www.andnowuknow.com/']
        start_urls = ["https://www.andnowuknow.com/"]

        rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_start_url', follow=True),)

        def parse_start_url(self, response):
            return self.parse_item(response)

        def parse_item(self, response):
            urls = []
            for link in LinkExtractor(allow=(),).extract_links(response):
                urls.append(link)
                print(urls)
```

I'm just trying get it to print something at this point, nothing I've tried so far works.

It finishes with an exit code of 0, but won't print so I cant tell whats happening.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this all your code? Because it seems incomplete. There is a class defined, but do you create an instance of this class?

Comment: Are you required to use scrapy? There is plenty of Q&A about beautifulsoup that also allow access to web page contents...

Comment: This is my first time using a class, what would be the best way to create an instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely your messages log should give us some hints, but I see your `allowed_domains` has a URL instead of a domain. You should set it like this:

```py
allowed_domains = ["andnowuknow.com"]
```

[(See it in the official documentation)](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains)

Hope it helps.